# MYSQL retrieving data based on today's date

Tags: mysql

I have tried the following query like this assuming that the today's date is 25:

**Query1**

```
    SELECT m.member_name, m.mobile FROM member m, `club_name` c WHERE m.cabinet = 1 
and c.wmmr_report=0 and m.club_name=c.id and DAY(NOW()) > 26
```

**Query2**

```
    SELECT m.member_name, m.mobile FROM member m, `club_name` c WHERE m.cabinet = 1 
and c.wmmr_report=0 and m.club_name=c.id and DAY(CURDATE()) > 26
```

But in both the case data is being returned as if I have `not used DAY(NOW()) > 26` or `DAY(CURDATE()) > 26`

Comment: What you want to get, All the rows having date 25, or something else?

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I want all the rows if the current date is greater than 26 else no rows.

Comment: You should not get any records if you really used that query which I doubt.

Comment: Regardless of the year or month?  What you have would return 07/27/2014 as well as 01/28/2012, for instance.  Do you have a date field in the either of the tables?

Comment: That is clear. You work with the actual day and not with data in the database. So it has no effect to the result.

Comment: so... today's the 25th.... you're query is 25 > 26 false so no rows ever....  tomorrow still no rows.  26 > 26 false and then wednesday 27>26 so then you would get all rows lesss what's excluded by joins and and other limiting criteria  In essense, this query would only return data from the 27+ in a month.

Comment: what you perhaps intend to use is `m.some_date_column > curdate()`

Comment: @xQbert that is exactly I want, but I am getting all the rows today and can't make out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I want to send some reminder sms based on the resultset, which will return if today's date is greater than 25 actual date not in the DB, otherwise it will not send any reminder. is it not Possible?

Comment: If you just run `select day(now()) > 26, now()` you get 0 (False)  and aug 25th right?  and what happens if you just run `select now()`;

Comment: @xQbert - Yes if select day(now()) > 26 I am getting 0, You are right. then How should I go about it.

Comment: The only logical answer is your sysdate is off... Now() isn't aug 25th.

Comment: @xQbert - How can it be? If just select select day(now()), it is returning 25

Comment: Your right... `SELECT m.member_name, m.mobile 
FROM member m, club_name c 
WHERE m.cabinet = 1 
  and c.wmmr_report=0 
  and m.club_name=c.id 
  and DAY(NOW()) > 26` should return no rows....  something is seriously wacked...  can you recreate this issue on [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: @xQbert Thanks I will look what is going wrong, also try it on sqlfiddle. Thanks

Comment: This [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b975c2/3) shows that you should not get any records returned for the queries you have, since today it the 25th.

Comment: @Linger - Thanks, I wonder what went wrong. I also getting no rows in my system now.

Comment: This post should be closed or deleted since the error cannot be reproduced